# Laravel Livewire calculate values on blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have one dynamic blade where I put value in three text fields and store that value in array.

[image]

my blade look like this

in my Laravel Livewire controller I have bellow code

```
public $veriProducts = [];

public function render()
    {
        $products = Product::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->orderBy( $this->sortBy, $this->sortAsc ? 'ASC' : 'DESC');
 
        $products = $products->paginate($this->perPage);
        
        info($this->veriProducts);

        return view('livewire.products', [
            'items' => $products,
        ]);

    }

  public function addProduct()
    {
        $this->veriProducts[] = ['price' => '', 'quantity' => ''];
    }

    public function removeProduct($index)
    {
        unset($this->veriProducts[$index]);
        $this->veriProducts = array_values($this->veriProducts);
    }
```

here is my blade

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($veriProducts as $index => $orderProduct)
<tr>
<td>
<input type="number" name="veriProducts[{{$index}}][price]" class="border border-gray-300 form-control my-0 p-1 ring-blue-200 rounded-md" wire:model="veriProducts.{{$index}}.price" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="veriProducts[{{$index}}][quantity]" class="border border-gray-300 form-control my-0 p-1 ring-blue-200 rounded-md" wire:model="veriProducts.{{$index}}.quantity" />
</td>

<input type="number" name="veriProducts[{{$index}}][total]" class="border border-gray-300 form-control my-0 p-1 ring-blue-200 rounded-md" wire:model="veriProducts.{{$index}}.total" />
</td>

<input type="number" name="veriProducts[{{$index}}][pl]" class="border border-gray-300 form-control my-0 p-1 ring-blue-200 rounded-md" wire:model="veriProducts.{{$index}}.pl" />
</td>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

its working fine I am able to add rows and also array **$veriProducts** is also created fine.
How can I calculate total and P/L after quantity text box loose focus or some other

```
Total will be
price*quanrity

PL will be
20% less then total
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `PL`, and `Total` are not editable we can use an updated hook and set the `total` and `pl` values accordingly,

```php
    public function updatedVeriProducts()
    {
        $this->veriProducts = collect($this->veriProducts)
               ->map(function ($product) {
                   if ($product['price'] != '' && $product['quantity'] != '') {
                       $total = $product['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                       $product['total'] = round($total, 2);
                       $product['pl'] = round($total * 0.8, 2);
                   }
                   return $product;
               })->toArray();
    }
```

I have made use of the `collect` method by laravel to work with the array easily.

With the `if` condition, we enable the calculation of `total` and `pl` only when both `price` and `quantity` has some input values.

And to avoid long decimals, I rounded it to 2 decimal places with `round` function.